# Why do Vue Material dialogs tend to move off screen?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-cli, vue-material

I am using a dialog from Vue Material (https://vuematerial.io/components/dialog). If I follow the link and open the first custom dialog on the page, it moves to the top left of my screen, and I can only see a portion of the dialog. The same happens with the dialogs that I have in my Vue app, and no CSS seems to bring it to the center of my screen. I am trying to show an interactive map in a dialog. Is there any way to keep my Vue dialog in the center of the browser window so I could actually see all of it and use it?

My dialog has the following markup:

```
    <md-dialog :md-active.sync="showDialog">
      <md-dialog-title>Map</md-dialog-title>

      <interactivemap :lat="lat" :lon="lon" />

      <md-dialog-actions>
        <md-button class="md-primary" @click="showDialog = false">Close</md-button>
      </md-dialog-actions>
    </md-dialog>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.md-dialog-container {
  transform: translate(0%,0%) scale(1) !important;
}
```

Modified the answer given by https://stackoverflow.com/users/13602136/zed, and my dialogue now sits nicely in the centre of my screen

Answer (score 0):

It works the same in my browser: both at the docs and code sandbox.

When it's off the screen, the inner div (with the class `.md-dialog > .md-dialog-container`) has `transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1);`, pushing it off.

Edit: yea, every dialog box has this CSS bug. Try overriding it and/or notify the devs.

Comment: Apparently the devs are aware of this problem, I just hoped that there was a quick workaround. Will try overriding, or maybe I'll just switch to Materialise dialog boxes... Thanks!